# Get all the VBA macros of a workbook by JavaScript API for Excel

Tags: excel, vba, office-js, javascript-api-for-office

In VBA, we could use for example [Wb.VBProject.VBComponents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443982(v=vs.60).aspx) to fetch all the VBA macros of a workbook `Wb`.

Does anyone know if JavaScript API for Excel provides any object or function to access that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot get the VBA macros out of the workbook using JS APIs.

Out of curiosity, why would you want to do it? I.e., what would be the pitch you'd make for having us include this API?

~ Michael Zlatkovsky, developer on Office Extensibility team, MSFT

Comment: OK... let me pitch a little bit... First, VBA macros are a part of a workbook, and important part of the logic / program besides Excel formulas, i just don't see why your API should exclude that. Second, without VBA macros some reasoning / analyses about a workbook would be wrong or incomplete. For instance, Excel provides currently `Worksheet Relationship` and `Cell Relationship` under `Inquire`. These analyses are based on Excel formulas, however, two worksheets or two cells could well have a relationship via macros, i feel it is a pity that Excel ignores totally this aspect...

Comment: Third, it seems that VBProject.VBComponents in VBA are not much more complicated than a text. Maybe a small effort on your side of making that available in JavaScript API would open a window to many possibilities...

Comment: I still am not 100% clear what those possibilities are (what would you do with VBA text from JavaScript, where you can't execute the thing?), but it's duly noted, and I've entered it into our backlog.

Comment: Is there a formal way (via mail?) for me to enter this request, so that i could explain in more details?

Comment: Sure!  Why don't you file the idea on Uservoice:  https://officespdev.uservoice.com/.  And then link to it from back here as well, for cross-reference.

Comment: A little late, but it would be great if you could access VBA macros from the Javascript API.  It would be nice to get the functionality of VBA from the javascript API.

Answer (score 0):

I think this github project is what you're looking for:

https://github.com/vbaidiot/Ariawase/blob/master/vbac.wsf

Comment: sorry, is it related to javascript api for excel?