# Add-in Error: something went wrong and we couldn't start this add-in

Tags: sharepoint, localhost, ms-office, office365, excel-addins

I'm following this [link](http://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-in-office-online) to run an Excel add-in.

I have followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=78wFR5Rp_Mw) and configured localhost such that [Home-simple.html](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16390558/) works well in a browser:

[image]

I have written `SheetSwitcherManifest-online-3.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="TaskPaneApp">
  <Id>9475b9bb-ff88-476f-917d-33a9c632508a</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Microsoft</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="Sheet Switcher - 3" />
  <Description DefaultValue="Sheet Switcher - 3" />
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="Workbook" />
  </Capabilities>
  <DefaultSettings>
  <SourceLocation DefaultValue="http://localhost/Downloads/Excel-Add-in-JS-SheetSwitcher-master/TextEditor/Home-simple.html" />
  </DefaultSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteDocument</Permissions>
</OfficeApp>
```

However, uploading this add-in in Excel online gives an error:

[image]

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `DefaultValue="file:///Users/softtimur/Downloads/Excel-Add-in-JS-SheetSwitcher-master/TextEditor/Home-simple.html"`, this is definitely incorrect because the file needs to be hosted on IIS (https://), rather than being a file:// reference.

For `https://localhost:44300/Users/softtimur/Downloads/Excel-Add-in-JS-SheetSwitcher-master/TextEditor/Home-simple.html`, does that link work in the browser for you? It looks suspiciously like the `file://` one, with a `localhost:44300` prefix.  Did you set up your IIS server to point at the very root of the C: drive (that would be rather unusual)? It would be more common to have it point at a folder, and have the address look more like `https://localhost:44300/TextEditor/Home-simple.html`

Comment: The localhost link does not work for me in a browser. I have not set anything about IIS server; additionally, i am using Mac. I agree that the issue probably comes from there, i am investigating it...

Comment: You can always get a free Azure website and publish to it -- using it as if it were your "localhost".  Or use the IIS equivalent on the Mac (Node's guilp would be one example; see https://github.com/OfficeDev/generator-office where it's used)

Comment: OK... i think i will be able to figure it out... By the way, Michael, for [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37127197/702977), did my comments make sense for you?

Comment: By the way, yesterday, i attended an event organised by your team, met some of stuff of your team, but i didn't mention that issue to them...

Comment: Finally, i followed [this thread](https://getgrav.org/blog/mac-os-x-apache-setup-ssl) to set up SSL, and it works...